# EF: PROBLEM WITH DBCONTEXT ACCESS FROM 2 DIFFERENT System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, system.timers.timer

I have a problem with my console app. I have a main static class contains the dbcontext as public property. When i start the app, my static class execute the following method:

`

```
  private static void CaricaDatabaseLotti()
        {
            try
            {
                RiempitoriBinsManager.SetRiempitori(ModelLotti.Riempitori.
              Include("BinsAccatastati").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Prodotto").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Confezione").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate").
                Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate.DettagliBolla").
              Where(x => x.RiempitoreId >= 1 && x.RiempitoreId <= 13).ToArray());

                PallettizzatoriManager.SetRiempitori(ModelLotti.Riempitori.
            Include("BinsAccatastati").
            Include("Bins.Riempimenti").
            Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Prodotto").
            Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Confezione").
            Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti").
            Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate").
                            Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate.DettagliBolla").

            Where(x => x.RiempitoreId >= 14 && x.RiempitoreId <= 19).ToArray());

                RapidPackManager.SetRiempitori(ModelLotti.Riempitori.
              Include("BinsAccatastati").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Prodotto").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Confezione").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti").
              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate").
                              Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate.DettagliBolla").

              Where(x => x.RiempitoreId >= 20 && x.RiempitoreId <= 29).ToArray());


                RiempitoriScartiManager.SetRiempitori(ModelLotti.Riempitori.
                   Include("BinsAccatastati").
                   Include("Bins.Riempimenti").
                   Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Prodotto").
                   Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Confezione").
                   Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti").
                   Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate").
                                   Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate.DettagliBolla").

                   Where(x => x.RiempitoreId >= 32 && x.RiempitoreId <= 36).ToArray());

                BoxFillersManager.Riempitori=(ModelLotti.Riempitori.
                  Include("BinsAccatastati").
                  Include("Bins.Riempimenti").
                  Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Prodotto").
                  Include("Bins.Riempimenti.Confezione").
                  Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti").
                  Include("Bins.Riempimenti.RigheRiempimenti.BolleEntrate").

                  Where(x => x.RiempitoreId >= 30 && x.RiempitoreId <= 31).ToArray());


                PallettizzatoriManager.Pallettizzatori = ModelLotti.Pallettizzatori.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(6).ToArray();
                RapidPackManager.Pallettizzatori = ModelLotti.Pallettizzatori.Where(x => x.Id >= 7).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(10).ToArray();
                BoxFillersManager.Pallettizzatori = ModelLotti.Pallettizzatori.Where(x => x.Id >= 17).OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(2).ToArray();

                Stages = ModelLotti.Stages.ToArray();

                var left = Stages[0];
                var right = Stages[1];

                var stagesids = Stages.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();


                var lottistage1 = ModelLotti.Lotti.Include("Parametri")
                    .Include("Parametri.CodiciSpecie")
                    .Include("BolleEntrate")
                    .Include("BolleEntrate.DettagliBolla")
                    .Include("Stages")
                    .Where(x => x.Stages.Select(c =>c.Id).ToList().Contains(left.Id));
                var lottistage2 = ModelLotti.Lotti.Include("Parametri").Include("Parametri.CodiciSpecie").Include("BolleEntrate").Include("BolleEntrate.DettagliBolla").Include("Stages").Where(x => x.Stages.Select(c=>c.Id).ToList().Contains(right.Id));

                LottoCorrenteCal1 = lottistage1.Where(x => x.LottoId == lottistage1.Max(X => X.LottoId)).FirstOrDefault();
                LottoCorrenteCal2 = lottistage2.Where(x => x.LottoId == lottistage2.Max(X => X.LottoId)).FirstOrDefault();

                RiempitoriBinsManager.Navetta.SetBinsABordo(ModelLotti.BinsSuNavettaPieni);

                CronologiaScarichi.CaricaUltimiScarichi();
                CronologiaScarichiNavettaPallet.GetUltimi30Scarichi();
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ModelLottiException(ex);
            }
        }
```

`

Then I have 2 different timers they access to DbContext, do their job and call ModelLotti.SaveChanges() if necessary. Sometimes, my context fault like:

1- New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session
2- The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction

I cannot use just one timer, I need they work totally indipendent. how can I avoid these exeptions?
I need to create 2 different dbcontext one for each timer?

I try to implement a method like these for restore datas

`

```
  internal static void SalvaLottiContext()
        {
            try
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Richiesta commit database Lotti...");
                
                if (ModelLotti.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
                {
                    ModelLotti.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("Database Lotti Salvato.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogRegister.Warning("ERRORE SALVATAGGIO DB LOTTI: " + ex.Message + ex.InnerException?.Message + ex.InnerException?.InnerException?.Message + ". StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);

                RipristinaModello();
            }
        }

        internal static void RipristinaModello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Database Lotti Ripristinato.");

            try
            {
                ModelLotti = new ModelLotti();

                CaricaDatabaseLotti();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Impossibile Ripristinare Database Lotti.");
            }

        }
```

`

Comment: Why are you using the `String`-based `Include` overloads instead of the `Expression<Func<>>` based overloads?

Comment: *Don't* use the DbContext from different threads to begin with. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It's not thread-safe and meant to be created as late as possible and disposed as early as possible

Comment: `ModelLotti.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` isn't needed either. A DbContext detects all changes to the objects it tracks and persists *all* of them in a single database transaction. `SaveChanges` won't do anything if there are no changes to save. Assuming `ModelLotti` is a DbContext, it should be created in a `using` block, ensuring it gets disposed in case of exception. This discards all pending changes and is in effect a "rollback"

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis for your response... if I'm working with event handlers, attaching methods to the handler, i need to implement  using(var model = new ModelLotti())  for each method??? =OOO

Comment: @LucaPannozzo _"i need to implement using(var model = new ModelLotti()) for each method"_ - **yes**, that is how EF's DbContext is meant to be used. But it's nothing to be concerned about. And it doesn't mean you need to repeat all of your Linq query definitions.